# How to display the classpath build in an Ant Junit task

Tags: ant

An Ant junit  task that has worked for months is suddenly failing with a NoClassDefFoundError for classes that used to be found.  Is there a way to display the classpath that is built in the junit task?

```
<target name="basic-junit-test" description="Run a single JUnit test. ">

    <junit printsummary="yes" fork="no" haltonfailure="yes">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="target/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/> 
            .
            . many other pathelements
            .
        </classpath>
        <test name="com.mycompany.command.TestUNLOCKACCOUNTCommand" outfile="${report.dir}/junit_test_results" />
    </junit>
</target>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a big fan of declaring my Ant paths at the top of my build and using classpath references in the various tasks.

To [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task can be used to print the classpath contents as a property:

```
<path id="test.path">
    <pathelement location="target/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/> 
    .
    . many other pathelements
    .
</path>

<target name="echo-path" description="Echo test path">
    <pathconvert targetos="unix" property="test.path.unix" refid="test.path">
    <echo message="Test path: ${test.path.unix}"/>
</target>

<target name="basic-junit-test" depends="echo-path" description="Run a single JUnit test. ">

    <junit printsummary="yes" fork="no" haltonfailure="yes">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="test.path"/>
        </classpath>
        <test name="com.mycompany.command.TestUNLOCKACCOUNTCommand" outfile="${report.dir}/junit_test_results" />
    </junit>
</target>
```

## Update

Just occurred to me: an even simpler solution might be to run Ant in debug mode.

Comment: Mark, Thanks  for the reply.  I'll  give it a try.  Can you tell me how to run Ant from Eclipse in debug mode?

Comment: To run Ant in Eclipse in debug mode use => AntFile in Ant Editor | Context Menu | Run As | 2 Ant Build... | Main Tab | Arguments => -debug then Run

Comment: Rebse, that is very useful.  The info that is printed in  debug mode is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Mark,  just  wanted to  let you  know I changed all my ANT path definitions to the format you suggested.  Your method is clear and easy to manage.  Way better than cramming everything into a junit task.

Comment: @user903724 I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the answer to my question, Mark O'Connor and Rebse gave excellent answers, instead this is a more thorough explanation of what happened to cause me to ask the question  in the first place.  I had an ANT Junit task that I had used to develop about 100 controller classes.  I used it for the first time in several months and every test failed with a classNotFound exception.  The  class that was not found was one that I was sure should be on the  classpath, it was a locally created jar file that is automatically picked up for the build.  I thought that somehow the classpath was at fault so I wanted to  display it when a test was run.

After many attempts to  figure out what was going on I put a try block around the code that was producing the classNotFound exception and I saw that the local class was not the class that was not being found.  This lead me to a search of the lib directory and eventually (after about six hours) I realized that the problem was that I had replaced an older version of slf4j-api with a newer version.  There was a dependency  on  a method that was in the older version but not in the newer.

Comment: Ouch! I can recommend using a dependency management tool like ivy. It would manage all your build's 3rd party jars and ensure that two versions of the same jar are not present. This is one of the key improvements to Java builds introduced by Maven. See: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/

Comment: Mark, would  Ivy protect me from my own stupidity in this  case? Would it know that the  newer jar did not  contain the method that was being used  in the older jar?

Comment: In this case ivy would ensure that only one version of each dependency was used. Normally this would be latest version on the assumption that most versions would be backwardly compatible and contain the latest methods. Of course this does not protect you in all cases, but it's certainly a start. The really big deal about ivy is that it plugs into the Maven repository infrastructure, which means open source libraries can be automatically downloaded with all their dependencies. It's all a bit magically, but certainly worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Mark's answer just helped me, but just a quick note as I needed to close the pathconvert xml element when copying the example in the answer.

```
<pathconvert targetos="unix" property="test.path.unix" refid="test.path" />
```